# Creating aggregated dataset in Python for analysis

Tags: python, r, group-by

I'm an R user and am learning Python, and am trying to create an aggregated dataset in Python as I would do in R or SQL.  However, Python is acting differently than I expected -- and I'm not sure how to create a dataset in the format I need for my work.

**R**

```
library(dplyr)

# Create sample data
team <- c("Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees")
pos <- c("Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher")
age <- c(24, 28, 40, 22, 29, 33, 31, 26, 21, 36, 25, 31)

baseball_example <- data.frame(team, pos, age)
  
average_age_by_team_position <- baseball_example %>% group_by(team, pos) %>% summarise(mean_age = mean(age))

print(average_age_by_team_position)
```

This output looks as follows:

team    pos         mean_age
             
1 Red Sox Not Pitcher     28
2 Red Sox Pitcher         30.7
3 Yankees Not Pitcher     30.7
4 Yankees Pitcher         26

**When I try to do this in Python, the grouped columns look different.  This means I can't use the output as the basis for further analysis, or exporting as a csv file**

**Python**

```
import pandas as pd

baseball_example = {"team": ["Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees"],
        "pos": ["Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher"],
        "age": [24, 28, 40, 22, 29, 33, 31, 26, 21, 36, 25, 31]}
        
baseball_example=pd.DataFrame(baseball_example)

average_age_by_team_position = baseball_example.groupby(['team', 'pos']).agg("mean")

print(average_age_by_team_position)
```

> ```
>                        age
> ```

team    pos
Red Sox Not Pitcher  28.000000
Pitcher      30.666667
Yankees Not Pitcher  30.666667
Pitcher      26.000000

**Can anyone advise how to create a version of Python code that has output that looks like R?**

Thank you! :)

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Following my question, I did a bit more research and found an answer.  It looks like this comes down to how Python uses indices.

It can be addressed by resetting the index, as shown below:

```
average_age_by_team_position = average_age_by_team_position.reset_index()
print(average_age_by_team_position)
```

I found this on the following site:
https://jamesrledoux.com/code/group-by-aggregate-pandas